# Remove sensitive data from development copies of production database (is there a gem for this?)

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, backup, security

I make nightly backups of my database using the excellent [backup gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup).  We also need to make copies of our production data for installation on staging, test and development databases.

But since the production database has sensitive information (emails, names, encrypted passwords, etc.) we want to sanitize the database before it leave the secured world of our production servers.

At some level, in our case, this could be as simple as replacing emails with `user+id@example.com` and replacing encrypted passwords and so on -- simple replacement of a few columns of data.  At this point, we could dump the database to a file that developers could use to have a realistic, working, but not real copy of the database.

This seems like something we should all be doing.  And while it's not terribly hard technically, I hate doing things someone else has already done better :-)  Does anyone know of a gem that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this will do what you're looking for:

http://sunitparekh.github.io/data-anonymization/

Comment: Thanks Rich -- a short skim makes this look like a pretty useful gem indeed.  Subsequent to my question, I have not found the backup gem I referenced that useful; this one is exactly what we want.

Comment: The provided link won't load in most browsers anymore because of mixed content (although you can override that security setting at your own risk). Just go to directly to the repo instead, https://github.com/sunitparekh/data-anonymization.

Answer (score 1):

The **Fake** gem is a good option to create fake data: https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker

Answer (score 0):

I have used Replibyte in the past and it is exactly what you described. It is a blazingly fast tool to seed your databases with your production data while keeping sensitive data safe. It works on MacOS, Windows and Linux.

Replibyte Supports data dump and restore for PostgreSQL, MySQL and MongoDB. It also Replace sensitive data with fake data.

https://github.com/Qovery/replibyte

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Ethan sorry for being lazy with my initial answer. i have updated the post with more details. hope its helpful for others!